# Incorrect Sorting when Converting a Time Column from 24 to 12 Hr Format

Tags: mysql, sql

Did someone notice this? and if so how to fix this?

when Im sorting a data by time I do this.

`SELECT TimeColumn FROM Table ORDER BY TimeColumn ASC`

the code above is good but when I do this.

`SELECT date_format(TimeColumn, '%h:%i %p') AS TimeColumn FROM Table ORDER BY TimeColumn ASC`

The sorting is incorrect.

How to fix this? TYSM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are renaming the expression with the same name as the column.  The alias is used for the sort -- and it does not sort right.

Just use the qualified column name:

```
SELECT date_format(TimeColumn, '%h:%i %p') AS TimeColumn
FROM Table t
ORDER BY t.TimeColumn ASC;
```

Or, give the column a different name:

```
SELECT date_format(TimeColumn, '%h:%i %p') AS TimeColumn_hh12
FROM Table t
ORDER BY TimeColumn ASC;
```

Comment: so you mean is I will stick to the columns name for the sorting then different name for the `AS` to fix my prob.